# Air flow at the outlet of a reactor

Tags: fluid-mechanics, propulsion

I wish to calculate the air flow in cubic meters per second of a system that is not exactly a jet engine, but seems close to it, mathematically speaking.

The data available to me is the following :

- the engine rotates at 3600 rpm
- the propeller is 40cm in diameter and is equipped with 16 blades, 5cm deep (but I don't know the pitch)
- the propeller air inlet is 20cm in diameter and the air outlet is 9cm in diameter
  normal temperature and pressure conditions (20 ° C - 1 atm).

I have only basic knowledge in maths and physics and I don't know where to start from there. As I am only looking for an indicative result, simple formulas could certainly help me.

I would be happy if someone could point me in the right direction. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: This is way beyond the capability of regular calculations.  I bet even a company like Hartzell who builds fans for a living would start with some idea based on past designs and then build it and test it.  Obviously the pitch and shape of the fan blades would matter a great deal.  Also, this isn't a "Reactor," unless you're talking about the system it's connected to.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I just wanted to say that it looks roughly like a reactor, considering the propeller and the presence of an air inlet and outlet.
I can provide additional data on the propeller blades, but I don't know which ones to provide. This is the meaning of my question : I'm asking what do I need to move forward.

Comment: I doubt this is anywhere within the capability of anything but the most specialized fan design software.  Are you building this from scratch?  The manufacturer should've tested it and provided a flow curve.